# Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MCSessionDelegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i want to write a simple code to test "MultipeerConnectivity"
so i use Type 'ViewController' to inherit "MCSessionDelegate" and "MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate"

but swift always say error like Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MCSessionDelegate'

i see oc code it is easy to realize it,why i change to swift ,it become wrong?

Comment: Do you implement all the required methods?  (Show code.)

Answer (score 3):

The `does not conform to protocol` error appears when you don't implement the required methods of this protocol.

In that case, to conform to the `MCSessionDelegate` you need to implement
 `session:didReceiveData:fromPeer:`,
 `session:didStartReceivingResourceWithName:fromPeer:withProgress:`,
 `session:didFinishReceivingResourceWithName:fromPeer:atURL:withError:`,
 `session:didReceiveStream:withName:fromPeer:` and 
 `session:peer:didChangeState:`

Take a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCSessionDelegateRef/), it lists all the required methods for the delegate.

Comment: Added missing: `func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState)`